# sessionStorage won't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session

Ok so i have this input "textmoney" that takes the users input and shows how much money they can make a year. When the user presses enter a link will pop up that goes to another page that gives a more precise estimate of the first answer. I want to have the second page to have a sessionStorage of "textmoney" from the first page, so that the user will not have to type in the data again. I coded this and i just can't seem to work at all. What did i do wrong?

First page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

    var $demo = $('#demo');
    var $textMoney = $('#textmoney');
    var $moneydiv = $('#moneydiv');
    // Store
    sessionStorage.setItem("textmoney", $textMoney.val());

    $('#advanced').hide();

    function getmoney(){
        var money = $textMoney.val();
            if (isNaN(money) || money === '') {
                $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
            } else {
                var dailyE = $textMoney.val() * 365;
                $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
            }
    }

    // on enter key
    $textMoney.keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            getmoney();
            $('#advanced').show();
        } else if ($(this).val() === '') {
            $demo.text('');
            $('#advanced').hide();
        }

    }).mouseover(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid black');
    }).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).css('border', '1px solid grey');
    });

    // on click 
    $moneydiv.click(function(){    
        getmoney();
        $('#advanced').show();
    });

});
    </script>
```

Second page:

```
<body>
    <p id="workp"> How many days a week do you work? </p>
    <input type="text" id="workdays">
    <hr id="line1">

    <p id="taxesp"> What percent of taxes does the Government take? </p>
    <input type="text" id="taxes">
    <hr id="line2">

    <p id="bonusp"> What's your average yearly bonus? </p>
    <input type="text" id="bonus">
    <hr id="line3">

    <p id="demo"></p>
    <div id="calculate"> Calculate </div>

    <a href="moneyperday.html"> Back to calculator </a>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(document.ready(function() {
        var $money = sessionStorage.getItem('textmoney');

        var $workdays = $('#workdays').val() * 52;
        var $moneynow = $money * $workdays;
        var $taxes = $('#taxes').val() / 100;
        var $bonus = $('#bonus').val();
        var $totalbalance = $moneynow * $taxes + $bonus;
        var $calculate = $('#calculate');


        function getmoney() {
            $demo.text($totalbalance + " " + "per day");
        }

        //on click
        $calculate.click(function() {
            getmoney();
        }


    })
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first page, you're setting the sessionStorage as soon as the page loads. You need to do that when they submit:

```
function getmoney(){
    var money = parseInt( $textMoney.val() );
    sessionStorage.setItem("textmoney", money ); // Right here
    if (isNaN(money) || !money ) {
        $demo.text('You aint enter no $$$$$$');
    } else {
        var dailyE = money * 365;
        $demo.text('$' + dailyE + ' per day');
    }
}
```

Also notice the `parseInt()` I added, just to make sure the value is treated as a number, not a String (Although in most browsers it will work without it).